# Advanced iOS Prototyping tool

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, prototyping

I'm looking for an advanced iOS prototyping tool. Here are some of the requirements that would be necessary for me to use one:

1. Should be able to run on a device and respond like a real app does. I don't mind if the prototype runs in a container.
2. Should be able to rotate a UITableView horizontally (like in Pulse/BBC) and also support gestures on the table.

I've seen some prototyping tools but none of them seem to support my second requirement above.  My only alternative seems to be coding, which I do not want to do at this stage because there are a lot of other details that would end up making the prototype too-much-to-handle. Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are putting too much effort into a prototype which (I'll assume) is going to be thrown away once you start implementing the real deal.

Ask yourself what you want to accomplish with a prototype.

Is it to test your navigation and design with users to see if it is intuitive and complete? In that case I would recommend that you write no code at all and make a prototype in something like Keynote. you can even use that to make a clickable PDF that you can view in full screen on the device to let users tap on buttons etc. Check out [the instructional videos on Keynotopia here](http://keynotopia.com/) for an example of what I'm talking about. I've even bought their awesome templates and love prototyping this way.

Is it to see if a specific technical thing can actually be done? In that case do minimal UI and write your code for real.

Comment: I would second this.  There is a school of thought among the UX profession that the tool you want for this is a packet of post-it notes, some sharpies, and a pair of scissors.  It allows you to experiment with user interactions, yet the prototypes are so cheap and throwaway that nobody will become attached to any design.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to just develop a wireframe, you can use control dragging and drag & drop interfaces within Storyboard in Xcode. If you want to do anything else, you'll need to at least add some code behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Best prototyping tool I've found is [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blueprint-lite/id407188253?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) . 
It's free too. But I agree 100% with @Heiberg above - don't waste your time perfecting the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Blueprint has been removed by Apple recently. App Cooker would be the best option for you with the free viewer called App Taster. A big update is coming, the price will go up. It's the right time to jump in. www.appcooker.com

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Heiberg that a long involved prototyping process isn't worth it. The [iOS prototyping tool I built, Flinto](https://www.flinto.com) takes that to heart. We focused a lot of our effort on making the process of creating the prototype very fast.

Gesture support is forthcoming. Rotation is handled by dedicated portrait and landscape versions of your prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with [AppCooker for the iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/appcooker-mockup-prototype/id418861662?mt=8). It has also free reader, called AppTaster, so other people can try your prototypes.

It's not 100% perfect, and update cycle is rare, but I like it. 
It supports gestures, but doesn't support rotation.